# How do I drop all IDs if their maximum value in a column is less than x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a DF in pandas with some names and need to drop ones that have a maximum number of items bought under 10.

```
| Name     | Cumulative items bought |
| -------- | -------- |
| Nick     |  2   |
| Nick     |  7   |
| Nick     |  11  |
| Jason    |  3   |
| Jason    |  5   |
| Kyle     |  2   |
| Kyle     |  7   |
| Kyle     |  9   |
```

For this example, I would want to drop all rows with Jason and all rows with Kyle

I am not sure how to drop all rows associated with a variable but also not dropping all rows associated with 'Nick' per say. I want to keep all the rows that involve him, not just the one where his cumulative sum is over 10.

I tried this:

```
df.drop(df[df['Cumulative items bought'] < 10].index)
```

This caused all of the observations to get dropped.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
out = df[df.groupby('Name')['Cumulative items bought'].transform('max').ge(10)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use filter to keep only groups which have a max value >= 10

```
df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x: x['Cumulative items bought'].max()>=10)
```